# Python : How should I send data values to web-server and get result using python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get the output page once we submit input on this page. http://batblob.com
Below is my code but it is giving me the html code of same page rather than of output page. 
I am on Python 2.7, Please suggest me how should I get there. 
Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://batblob.com'
session = requests.Session()

form = {
            'bitadd':'anybitcoinaddress',
            'submit': 'submit',
        }

r = requests.post( url, data=form)
response = session.get(url)

html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup
```

Comment: Of course it does not work, you don't use the session to post, also you seem to need to login to use the service

Answer (score 0):

In this case the data you want is already in your **r** variable. I would assume the following will get what you are after.

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://batblob.com'
form = {
    'bitadd':'anybitcoinaddress',
    'submit': 'submit',
}

# Post form data and parse response
response = requests.post(url, data=form)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

print(soup)
```

Comment: This is also giving the same result.